# How to increase IIS processes priority (for both w3wp and iis apppool)?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, remoting

There is an ASP.NET application with a set of web services, and there is a WinForms application that calls these web services.

The w3wp.exe (which handles asmx calls) run special processes that do a really "hard" jobs (like zipping, xml parsing, etc.). It is a long story why we need it to be done in separate processes and why we don't run this code inside w3wp.exe - this doesn't matter here. It must be like that.

If multiple requests came simulteneously from many users, there can be 30-40 such processes, and they consume CPU. They consume it so much that almost no CPU resources is left for IIS itself.

**So, the problem is next: when the following HTTP requests are coming to this IIS,  IIS cannot handle them:  it cannot even pass them to w3wp.exe because server is "bombed".**  And, as a result, in peak time 30 users have run their queries, and 31st user is getting a WebException in the WinForms client "timeout expired".

I have found a lot of articles in the internet which explain how to tweak IIS, but noone take into account the fact that OTHER processes and/or applications can run on the same machine. And noone tells what to do to make so that IIS is of higher priority.

**So, the question is next: is there a way to "explain" IIS that it should start by default the apppool (svchost.exe) and w3wp.exe with hiher priority?**

Comment: How about starting the "special processes" with a lower priority?

Comment: Sounds like time to add more hardware.

Comment: @AaronS it sounds more like bad application design. If the server gets flooded by doing 30 things at once, then it should spread the tasks out over time. You can easily develop ASP.NET applications that perform tasks asynchronously and report back to the user when background-tasks are done.

Comment: why people are making conclusions WITHOUT knowing the domain?

Comment: it is long to explain why code which is doing some job is running in those separate processes. this is related to COM (one Microsoft't COM object) which doesn't release memory and which doesn't work fine in the case if 2 instances of this object is working in ONE process.  This is the reason why code is not working inside w3wp.exe and is placed in separate process. But anyway, if this code worked in w3wp or not in w3wp - it would "bomb" the server very much - both CPU and hard drive.  So the question is more generic:  what to do with IIS in the case if something is "bombing" the server?

Comment: If you increase the priority of IIS then you are likely to end up needing to increase the priority of many other processes on the server. The alternative is to reduce the priority of the resource-intensive process so that IIS (and the rest of the system) can function normally. Can you put the resource-intensive process on another computer, or, as Dai implied, put the tasks in a queue and do not process so much at a time that the computer is bogged down?

Comment: if we decrease the priority of that "special" processes, another problem occurs:  when w3wp.exe and that process are communicating through remoting,  the remoting calls often break with exception "IPC channel has died" or something like this. And I don't know why. Most probably this is because of Microsoft .NET bugs in remoting implementation, whatever. But the process should be in "normal" priority in order to successfully connect to it though remoting.  So, the way out is to increase IIS process priority, OR redesing the whole app to move that "special" work on another server.

Comment: So, the question is how to increase priority of IIS still remains

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in Windows Server 2008 r2. 
I had a windows service (which used parallel processing) which used to bloat up my CPU a lot & left nothing for IIS & SQL Server.

So I set **processor affinity** to the windows service to consume only specific processors. 
You get in **Task Manager->RightClick Process -> Set Affinity.**

This left other processors free to use for SQL & IIS.

To an extent, It decreased the productivity of the windows service which was now working with a limited set of processors but it did not matter that much.